# Problema con el envío de correos desde proyecto subido a cpanel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

Tengo el siguiente problema: después de subir un proyecto en *laravel* al hosting *CPANEL*, me salio el siguiente error después de hacer pruebas con el modulo de recuperar contraseña. El error que me salio fue este:

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 277:
>   Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]

Lo que no entiendo es por qué cuando corro el proyecto localmente desde mi equipo, no me sale ningún error. Así que deduje que tiene que ver algo con las configuraciones en el *.env* o en el archivo *mail.php* de la carpeta *config*. Pero nada, el problema aún continua.

Estas son las configuraciones de mi archivo *email.php*

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
'from' => ['address' => 'kervheros@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Reivin'],
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

Estas son las configuraciones de mi archivo *.env*

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=w8yOf3KbFIDAU99dxWlwnXGo6N2IAZbk

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=imsur
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=aqui esta mi correo
MAIL_PASSWORD=aqui esta mi contraseña
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Alguien que me pueda decir qué es lo que esta mal y qué se podría hacer. Gracias.

Comment: Yo lo tengo funcionando para gmail  con puerto `MAIL_PORT=587` y no `465` y `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` y no `ssl`. También tienes que configurar tu cuenta de gmail para que dé 'Acceso a aplicaciones menos seguro', o si tienes activa la autenticación de 2 factores, debes agregar una nueva aplicación a la cuenta de Google y generar una contraseña dedicada para que funcione.

Comment: cambie los datos que mencionas en el .env y tambien hice las configuraciones en la cuenta de google pero como dije en mi pregunta el envio de correo funciona cuando corro el proyecto de manera local en mi equipo, pero la cosa cambia cuando lo corro cuando el proyecto ya esta en el hosting CPANEL

Comment: si tienes acceso por consola, limpia la cache de configuración, como te lo dicen en la respuesta abajo. Si no tienes consola ve a la carpeta `/bootstrap/cache` y elimina el archivo `config.php`, o cambiale el nombre al `config_copia.php` por ejemplo, si quieres guardar una copia de seguridad

Comment: no tengo el archivo config.php dentro de la carpeta cache solo esta el archivo services.json y en la carpeta bootstrap esta los archivos app.php y autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

Algo que que probaría es cambiar el mail driver:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

Si sigue sin funcionar, chequearía que tu hosting no esté bloqueando el puerto de envío por gmail mediante un firewall.
Recordá releer la cache de php:

```
php artisan cache:clear;
php artisan config:cache;
```

Comment: hice el cambio pero me salio el siguiente error:                                                                ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 304:
proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons

Comment: y con respecto a los comandos q dejaste donde los ejecuto en cpanel perdon por la ignorancia pero es la primera vez que subo un proyecto a un hosting